# How to pass additional parameters to the event handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using [node-ftp](https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp) library to get/put the file in ftp.

```
// establish a ftp connection
function connect(message) {
    client.connect(ftpProperties);
}


// once connection is successfully established, ready event will be emitted
client.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('ftp connection is success.');
  // do something
  // How to access message object here?
});
```

> **What i tried:** if i use ready event handler inside connect function it
>   got registered each time when ever i invoke a connect function.

Please suggest me how to pass a ***message*** object from connect function to ready event handler function?

Comment: I'd guess that whatever calls `connect` will have access to the `message`, so should be responsible for creating an event handler that *closes* over `message` and can be passed to `client.on('ready')` instead of the one you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to to register a one-timer event listener within your connect function.

```
function connect(message) {
  client.once('ready', function() {
    // use message
  });
  client.connect(ftpProperties);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save it in an array and use it later on:

```
var myArray = new Array(); //create an array

// establish a ftp connection
function connect(message) {
    client.connect(ftpProperties);
    myArray.push(message);
}



// once connection is successfully established, ready event will be emitted
client.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('ftp connection is success.');

  console.log(myArray[0]); //use it here

});
```